Parametric Representation of Polar Integral
I am trying to derive the formula for the area under a polar curve, which is $\int_{}^{}(\frac{1}{2}r^2)d\Theta$.
I am using the formula for the area under the parametric curve $(f(\Theta), g(\Theta))$, which is $\int_{}^{}(g(\Theta)f'(\Theta))d\Theta$.
When I plug this into the equation for the area under parametric curves, I get $f(\Theta)=r*cos(\Theta)$ and $g(\Theta)=r*sin(\Theta)$, so $f'(\Theta)=\frac{dr}{d\Theta}cos(\Theta)-r*sin(\Theta)$.
However, when I was testing to see if my first step was correct in a calculator, I found that $\int_{}^{}(r*sin(\Theta)(\frac{dr}{d\Theta}cos(\Theta)-r*sin(\Theta)))d\Theta=-\int_{}^{}(\frac{1}{2}r^2)d\Theta$. What am I doing wrong here?

Where did you get that formula for "the area under the parametric curve $(f(\Theta), g(\Theta))$"? I cannot figure an interpretation for this description where that formula makes sense. If $(f(\Theta), g(\Theta)) = (r,\theta)$ (polar coordinates), then the area is $$\int_{\Theta_0}^{\Theta_1}\int_0^{f(\Theta)}r,dr,g'(\Theta)d\Theta = \int_{\Theta_0}^{\Theta_1}\frac 12(f(\Theta))^2g'(\Theta)d\Theta$$

I used Paul's Online Notes (https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/paraarea.aspx), which puts it in the following terms: the area under $(f(t), g(t))=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}g(t)f'(t)dt$. I let $f(t)=rcos(\theta)$ and $g(t)=rsin(\theta)$ and plugged in from there. (Just using $\theta$ as my variable instead of $t$.)

That is for CARTESIAN COORDINATES. The "area under the curve* refers to the region between the curve and the $x$-axis. But you are using POLAR COORDNATES and "the area under the curve* refers to the region between the curve and the origin. It is a different region, and has a different area.

Thank you, I understand what you mean now.
